# How do you know when an operation should be performed synchronously or asynchronously in smart contract tests?

Tags: mocha, chai

What operations are usually perform asynchronously in smart contract tests, and what operations are usually performed synchronously in smart contract tests? When are each of these usually used?

Answer (score 1):

It is simple actually, you use `async` and `await` when you want to wait for the return value.

Let us look at the example here,

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
require("dotenv").config();

const { ALCHEMY_API_KEY } = process.env;

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  `https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/${ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`
);

const address = `0x30AE003d9c29Cd9D403F84312744B0f1abcae95c`;

const main = async () => {
  const balance = await provider.getBalance(address);
  console.log(
    `The balance of ${address}: ${ethers.utils.formatEther(balance)}`
  );
};

main().catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

It is a simple program in ether.js that will show the balance of an ethereum wallet.

```
const main = async () => {
  const balance = await provider.getBalance(address);
  console.log(
    `The balance of ${address}: ${ethers.utils.formatEther(balance)}`
  );
};
```

In the above function, you can see I am using await while requesting the balance. Because I know the method `provider.getBalance(address)` would return promise. And I should wait for the promise to return.

And when I am trying to console.log the balance of an address, it is depended on the result of the query above. So I know I should wait for the result to log the balance.

If I do not wait, I will get an error like this:

> Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value={}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)
> at Logger.makeError (/home/adhoc/blockDev/prep/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:238:21)
> at Logger.throwError (/home/adhoc/blockDev/prep/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247:20)
> at Logger.throwArgumentError (/home/adhoc/blockDev/prep/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:250:21)
> at Function.BigNumber.from (/home/adhoc/blockDev/prep/node_modules/@ethersproject/bignumber/lib/bignumber.js:239:23)
> at formatFixed (/home/adhoc/blockDev/prep/node_modules/@ethersproject/bignumber/lib/fixednumber.js:43:35)
> at formatUnits (/home/adhoc/blockDev/prep/node_modules/@ethersproject/units/lib/index.js:67:40)
> at Object.formatEther (/home/adhoc/blockDev/prep/node_modules/@ethersproject/units/lib/index.js:84:12)
> at main (/home/adhoc/blockDev/prep/ether.js/1_accounts.js:15:48)
> at Object. (/home/adhoc/blockDev/prep/ether.js/1_accounts.js:19:1)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14) {
> reason: 'invalid BigNumber value',
> code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
> argument: 'value',
> value: Promise {  }
> }

It is simply saying promise is still pending and you aren't waiting for it complete it.

In simple words, if the method or function returns promises, you should use async and await. You can also think like, if the following code is dependant on the result of a method in my case balance, you should use await.

You can read more about async and await [here](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/modern-asynchronous-javascript-with-async-and-await/)

Tell me if it helps!

Comment: How do you know what functions or methods will return a promise, since there are so many functions and methods in the docs out there? What if I use async and await on a function that does not return a promise?

Comment: You have to read the docs and understand the methods for that. And reading examples that used those methods can help you too. If you use await for something that doesn't return any value, it'll simply throw an error ig